# When I capture a screenshot with shutter it opens automatically

Tags: shutter

How can i disable or remove this feature? When I take a screen-shot,it opens

[image]

Im using shutter
Edit:I solved it,thanks @2 i just didn't look the -help command

Comment: The picture shows a Mint desktop. Mint is not an official version of Ubuntu. It is off-topic here.

Comment: @user68186 it's a ubuntu-based distro man.Also there isn't any problem for mint,it is a general problem.If i use ubuntu,i'll have same problem

Comment: See the first bullet point under [Questions that you should avoid:](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic). If you can put up a screenshot of Ubuntu instead of Mint, I will withdraw the close vote.

Comment: @user68186 so, if i crop it? It's foolish.we are both linux users,and mint is very close to ubuntu, i can't understand it man.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`shutter` has `-e` or `--exit_after_capture` , which is what you're looking for. For example, using `shutter -a  -e` , you can capture the currently focused window and receive small popup notification that will let you know where screenshot file was saved, but no `shutter` window will be opened. This can be used in scripts or as keyboard shortcut. Please see `man shutter` for more info on other command-line switches that shutter has

Comment: how can I stop that small notification which appears after taking the screenshot?